# Can't start mysqld with myisam only

Tags: mysql

I have Mysql 5.6 in mac os lion but when I try to start the server without innodb it doesn't let me even though I've set the default storage engine to myisam. According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#option_mysqld_innodb) this should be achievable. I don't need innodb and it takes a lot of ram (>400mb) and cpu load. I've tried launching mysqld, mysql.server, launchctl. I both used a config file and command line parameters.

My my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]
#skip-innodb
default-storage-engine=myisam
innodb=off

#query-cache-type=0
#max_user_connections=2

#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2M
#sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Here is the output:

```
2013-10-04 16:44:49 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [ERROR] Aborting

2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Binlog end
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2013-10-04 16:44:49 8041 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: You have an error in your config file, Start the server manually from a command line to find out what

Comment: What is the error? I've also tried to launch from command line. I've added the results.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd *want* only MyISAM. It's a terrible storage engine that can corrupt itself way too easily.

Comment: MyiSam runs in next to no memory. uncomment skip-innodb and comment innodb = off

Comment: @user1281385 - memory exists for a reason and that reason is to use it  in order to improve performance. Not using memory is not an excuse, people who are bent on saving RAM for no purpose have no business in IT.

Comment: @N.B. Agreed, but if you have a low end server (<256 ram) im usually willing to loose some of the innodb features.

Comment: I've used skip-innodb too.